# org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to build a proof of concept for microservices in java (eclipse) using Spring libraries. Due to certain restrictions, I am not using Maven, but I rather downloaded the following jar files manually and imported them to my java project.

[image]

My code is below:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorld{

    @RequestMapping("/")
    //http://localhost:port/
    String hello()
    {
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(HelloWorld.class);

        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.SERVLET);

        app.run(args);
    }


}
```

Unfortunately, when I run my code, I am getting the following errors. How can I run my program without failing to start the server?

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2019-08-29 11:33:59.550  INFO 15572 --- [           main] hello.HelloWorld                         : Starting HelloWorld on HQTPM146609D with PID 15572 (D:\Ramesh\ADMWorkspace\HelloWorldMicroservice\build\classes started by abdallah.alhodaly in D:\Ramesh\ADMWorkspace\HelloWorldMicroservice)
2019-08-29 11:33:59.554  INFO 15572 --- [           main] hello.HelloWorld                         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-29 11:33:59.682  INFO 15572 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@18a70f16: startup date [Thu Aug 29 11:33:59 GST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-08-29 11:34:00.473  WARN 15572 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
2019-08-29 11:34:00.485  INFO 15572 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-08-29 11:34:00.495 ERROR 15572 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at hello.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:30) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried with extending SpringBootServletInitializer

Comment: Don't download jars, use maven or gradle for that. In short your dependencies are a mess, you are mixing Spring 4.3, 5.0, 5.1 jars. Spring Boot jars from different versions. That is trouble waiting to happen and that happens when you start hunting the internet for jars yourself. Don't do things like that.